# Read file and identify a String between parenthesis

Tags: java, string, file

I am attempting to name the String that will occur between the last set of parenthesis "genesym". So far, I am swapping the last occurrence of each parenthesis with a tab character. Between these functions, I want to name that existing String genesym.

I realize this is a Scanner function, but this is the only way I know how to say it.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TESTING
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("human.rna.fna"));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("FormattedHumanRNA"));

            String line
            String genesym;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.startsWith(">")) {
                    // Replaces the last set of parenthesis with a tab character
                    int openbracket =  line.lastIndexOf("(");
                    line = new StringBuilder(line)
                        .replace(openbracket, openbracket + 1, "\t")
                        .toString();


                    **genesym = br.nextString();**


                    // Replaces the last close parenthesis with a tab character
                    int closebracket = line.lastIndexOf(")");
                    line = new StringBuilder(line)
                        .replace(closebracket, closebracket + 1, "\t")
                        .toString();
                } else {
                    line = line.replaceAll ("\n", "");
                }

                bw.write(genesym + " : " + line);
            }
            br.close();
            bw.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample: (my data is MUCH larger than this, around 1 million lines)

input file:

```
>365 (LOC1), long non-coding RNA AGCGTCT

>22 (1*split3**) (FLJ), long RNA AAAATC

>13 (RTV), RNA ATGCG
```

desired output:

```
LOC1 : >365      LOC1     , long non-coding RNA AGCGTCT

FLJ : >22 (1*split3**)      FLJ     , long RNA  AAAATC

RTV : >13     RTV     ,RNA ATGCG
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Can you include the input file you are reading and what you want your output to be?

Answer (score 0):

```
String genesym=line.substring(openbracket,closebracket);
```

Then replace what you want to replace.

Comment: String genesym = line.substring( lastIndexOf("("), lastIndexOf(")")  );
Why can't I do this?

Comment: String genesym = line.substring( line.lastIndexOf("("), line.lastIndexOf(")") );